# Motion Blur not Rendering in Eevee

Tags: rendering, animation, eevee-render-engine, motion-blur

I've just finished a big animation and as I'm about to render the motion blur isn't working! I have it turned on, and I messed around with all the settings. What's weird is in older renders of the animation the motion blur DID render, but now it isn't. Does it have to do with the lightning potentially?